# populate in mongoose returns empty array, i'm Stucked

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i'm creating simulation for goodreads by MERN stack 
and when i'm using populate to retrieve books of specific user it returns empty array, i've done alot of search but in vain
here's my model

```
const userSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
firstName:{
    type:"string",required:true
},
books:[{
    book:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Book'},rate:Number,shelve:''
}]});
```

and this is books model

```
const bookSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
title :{
    type:"string",required:true
}});
```

and this is how i use populate

```
router.get("/one", (req, res, next) => {
User.find({firstName : "John"}).populate("books").exec(function (err, user) { 
    res.json(user)
 });
})
```

and this is the resulted json

```
[{"_id":"5c70f299ef088c13a3ff3a2c","books":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing the object `book` inside books array, so you need to populate `books.book`.

```
User.find({firstName : "John"}).populate("books.book").exec(function (err, user) { 
   res.json(user)
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
i've tried it and it gave me array of _id 
like this 
    [{"_id":"5c70f299ef088c13a3ff3a2c","books":[{"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310b9"},{"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310ba"}]

but i need the content like title for example

Comment: ok then try using `.populate('books.book','title')` it might work.

Comment: still returning Id :/